# How to find canonical transformation to achieve desired Hamiltonian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I am trying to find a way to transformation that will turn a Hamiltonian from one form into another form:

$$(1)\;\;\;H=p^2+e^x\rightarrow\bar{H}=p'^2.$$

I don't know of any systematic ways to do this. I am simply going through trial and error. An example of one such "trial" is shown below:
$$(2)\;\;\;x=\ln (x'p')\longrightarrow\;x'=e^x/p'$$
Corresponding generating function given by
$$(3)\;\;\;\;\Phi=x'p'=e^x$$
$$(4)\;\;\;p=\dfrac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\;x}=e^x=e^{\ln{x'p'}}=x'p'$$

Sub $x$ and $p$ into Hamiltonian $H$
$$(5)\;\;\;\;\bar{H}=e^{2x}+x'p'=x'^2p'^2+x'p'$$

Trail failed because it is not of the form $\bar{H}=p'^2$.

Continuing with this approach is not great. I also have very little background so even this approach is most likely wrong. Specifically, I think that (3) is a mistake because I've been trying to follow a similar example and although they used the assumption (3), I think that the assumption for the form of the generating function is specific to the problem and therefore does not apply here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: From
$$ \frac{\partial W}{\partial q}~=~p~=~\pm\sqrt{P^2-e^q}\tag{1}$$

[Hamilton's characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) is

$$\begin{align} \pm W(q,P)~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~&\int \!\mathrm{d}q\sqrt{P^2-e^q}\cr ~=~&2\sqrt{P^2-e^q}-2 |P| {\rm artanh} \sqrt{1-\frac{e^q}{P^2}}+C(P),\tag{2}\end{align}$$
where $P\mapsto C(P)$ is an arbitrary function.

Then the new position coordinate is

$$Q~=~\frac{\partial W}{\partial P}~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~\mp 2{\rm sgn}(P){\rm artanh} \sqrt{1-\frac{e^q}{P^2}}\pm C^{\prime}(P).\tag{3}$$